# Axiom schema of separation in the constructible universe

Tags: logic, set-theory

For any formula $\varphi(x)$ exists an ordinal ${\alpha_0}$ such that for all $x \in L: $ $$L \models\varphi(x) \iff L_{\alpha_0} \models \varphi(x)$$ this makes sense, since all $x$ in $L$ that can have an impact on $\varphi(x)$ have to appear at some stage. Can I show this with induction over the complexity of $\varphi(x)$?

Because then for any $S \in L_{\alpha}$ and $\varphi(x)$ the set $ M':=\{x\in L_{\alpha}: x \in S \land L_{\alpha} \models \varphi(x)\}$ would be in $L_{\alpha+1}$. This isn't enough since for specification the Quantors need to look at at $L$ not $L_{\alpha}$, now I get an $\alpha_0$ for which I have the above equivalence and I would get the "real" $M$ in $L_{{\alpha_0}+1}$. Does this work?

Comment: Your very first sentence is false: what if $x\not\in L_{\alpha_0}$? (And some $\varphi$s will never be "fully captured" - consider $\varphi(x)\equiv$ "$x$ is an ordinal.") Instead, what you need for separation is that for every $\varphi$ there are unboundedly many ordinals $\alpha$ such that for all $x\in L_{\color{red}{\alpha}}$ we have $$L\models\varphi(x)\quad\iff\quad L_\alpha\models\varphi(x).$$ That is, a kind of "local" reflection.

Comment: It definitely makes more sense now, thanks for the example. So for every $\varphi$ I need an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $L \models \varphi(x) \iff L_\alpha \models \varphi(x)$ and that $\alpha$ can be bigger than any ordinal $\beta$. The second part of my question should work when "switch" $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha$. I could prove this local reflection with induction over the complexity of $\varphi$, right?